# doesn't pick up the if statements instead went to else

Tags: python, discord.py

This is what I have right now, the if statements feels like doesn't engaged in the code. I have also tried random.randint() but didn't work

```
async def open_huge_cat_case(ctx):
    huge_case = randint(1, 100)
    if huge_case == (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40):
        await ctx.send('1')
    if huge_case == (41, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65):
        await ctx.send('2')
    if huge_case == (66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85):
        await ctx.send('3')
    if huge_case == (86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95):
        await ctx.send('4')
    else:
        await ctx.send('5')
```

Comment: A number is never `==` to a tuple. Did you mean `in`?

Comment: `if huge_case <= 40` seems like a much more natural solution.

Comment: Experimenting by breaking your problem down into the smallest, simplest bit possible is a useful approach for solving these kinds of problems. For example, `huge_case = 1` then `print(huge_case == (1, 2, 3))` would immediately show you that the `==` operator doesn't doing what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare using `==` for a list (or tuple) of things, instead you need `in` like so:

```
async def open_huge_cat_case(ctx):
    huge_case = randint(1, 100)
    if huge_case in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40):
        await ctx.send('1')
    elif huge_case in (41, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65):
        await ctx.send('2')
    elif huge_case in (66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85):
        await ctx.send('3')
    elif huge_case in (86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95):
        await ctx.send('4')
    else:
        await ctx.send('5')
```

You also need `elif` as shown above to make sure only one executes at a time.

It would also be better to use `range()` like so:

```
huge_case = randint(1, 100)
    if huge_case in range(1, 41):
        await ctx.send('1')
    elif huge_case in range(41, 66)):
        await ctx.send('2')
    elif huge_case in range(66, 86):
        await ctx.send('3')
    elif huge_case in range(86, 96):
        await ctx.send('4')
    else:
        await ctx.send('5')
```

This makes it clearer and easier to write.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to pick a random string between '1' and '5', but with distinct weights.

You could simply use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) directly:

```
random.choices('12345', [40, 25, 20, 10, 5])[0]
```

The probability of it returning a `'1'` is 8 times higher than for a `'5'`. `random.choices` returns a list by default, but it looks like you're only interested in one value, hence the `[0]`.

Using `cum_weights` might be marginally faster than `weights`:

```
random.choices('12345', cum_weights=[40, 65, 85, 95, 100])[0]
```

And if you want multiple results at once:

```
random.choices('12345', cum_weights=[40, 65, 85, 95, 100], k=30)
#=> ['3', '1', '3', '1', '3', '5', '2', '2', '5', '4', '3', '3', '2', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '3', '3', '2', '5', '2', '2', '1', '3', '1', '1', '3']
```